# Apache mod_alias type functionality in IIS (10)

Tags: iis, iis-10, mod-alias

Wondering if it's possible to implement in IIS10 actions similar to those provided by mod_alias for Apache, specifically "Alias" to map a filename from an HTTP request to a common local path outwith that site's DocumentRoot or Physical Path rather than rewriting to an alternative location within the site or redirecting to another URL.

In Apache I have an "Alias" declaration configured at the global level:

`Alias /contact.php "/var/www/contact.php"`

This declaration is inherited by each VirtualHost (site definition) so that a call to "/contact.php" at any site (e.g.: https://example.com/contact.php etc) will cause the single common file "/var/www/contact.php" to be processed.

The configuration as described above simplifies site management since it is not necessary to deploy and maintain a duplicate file across multiple Web site content directories.

Is there a way to mimic this in IIS10?

I have looked at URL rewrites, application and virtual directory definitions among others and have been unable to find a configuration which exactly meets the requirement.

TIA

Comment: https://www.helicontech.com/ape/ "Helicon Ape is implemented as managed IIS 7 module and can be installed as .NET module on any ASP.NET-compatible IIS version. It works transparently for both server and client and can even be installed on a shared hosting account without administrative access." The technique is rather simple, so you can port mod_alias over the same way.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read and respond @LexLi.  I've looked at Helicon Ape previously in a different context and I will take a look to see if it's something which maybe fits here but ideally I'm looking to find out if there is a method to achieve this natively in IIS without additional third-party modules/products.

Comment: 1) I am not asking you to use anything from Helicon Ape, because they don't have a `mod_alias` equivalent yet based on the pages. 2) Not easy to find a native feature that mimics, so your best option might be developing your own extension (using the same approach Helicon Ape uses).